# Remove rows when a specific column value is present more than once

Tags: awk, sort

I am processing a lot of `.tsv` files through awk and I need to remove all the rows where we observe duplicates or more of the same values in column 2.

E.g.

```
a b c
value1 2 3
value2 2 5
value3 1 9
value4 1 0
value5 4 0
value6 1 0
```

should become

```
a b c
value5 4 0
```

I thought about using `sort -k2 filename | awk 'count[$2]++ > 1'`, but I get some weird results:

```
$ sort -k2 file.txt | awk 'count[$2]++ > 1' | wc
    162    4212   33348
$ sort -k2 file.txt | awk 'count[$2]++ == 1' | wc
   3954  102804  704176
$ wc file.txt
  1029257  26760682 176254913
```

...which doesn't make any sense, as their sum should be 1029257. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very similar to [@pLumo's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/721555/133219) but not comparing `NR` to `FNR` twice and not testing for `FNR` being `1` twice and handling the possibility of fields containing blanks:

```
$ awk -F'\t' '
    NR == FNR { if (NR > 1) cnt[$2]++; next } 
    cnt[$2] < 2
' file file
a       b       c
value5  4       0
```

or if you prefer:

```
$ awk -F'\t' '
    NR == FNR { cnt[$2] += (NR > 1); next }
    cnt[$2] < 2
' file file
a       b       c
value5  4       0
```

The negative to the above 2-pass approach is it can't handle input coming from a stream. If you need to handle that then this [DSU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71691113/how-to-sort-data-based-on-the-value-of-a-column-for-part-multiple-lines-of-a-f/71694367#71694367) approach can handle it without awk having to read all the input into memory (`sort` is designed to use demand paging etc. to handle huge input but we're not passing all of the input to `sort` anyway, just 2 or less lines per unique 2nd field value) while retaining the original order of input lines:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
    (cnt[$2] += (NR>1)) < 3 {
        print NR, cnt[$2], $0
    }
' "${@:--}" |
sort -t $'\t' -k4,4 -k1,1rn |
awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
    $4 != prev {
        if ( $2 < 2 ) {
            print
        }
        prev = $4
    }
' |
sort -t $'\t' -k1,1n |
cut -d $'\t' -f3-
```

With input from a file:

```
$ ./tst.sh file
a       b       c
value5  4       0
```

and with input from a stream/pipe:

```
$ cat file | ./tst.sh
a       b       c
value5  4       0
```

The above scripts will all work with any versions of awk, sort, and cut.

Answer (score 3):

`awk` goes through a file line by line, so you cannot know if the current line's field `$2` is uniqe in the file.

You need to open the file twice. First for counting, second time printing if `count[$2] == 1`.

```bash
awk '
    NR==FNR && FNR>1 {count[$2]++};
    NR>FNR && (FNR==1 || count[$2] == 1)
' file.txt file.txt
```

- `NR==FNR` is true on first file only, I add `FNR>1`, because we don't want to count the header.
- `NR>FNR` is true for the second file.

  - Print header (`FNR==1`) or if `count[$2]` is `1`.

Answer (score 1):

As pLumo described [in their answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/721555/116858), you can't know what records are unique until you've read them all once.  Their answer solves this by reading the file twice.  The other way to solve it is to read the data into memory.  You may want to do this if the amount of data is "small" (for some definition of "small" depending on your circumstances).

This could be done with `awk` like so:

```bash
awk 'NR == 1 { head = $0; next }
    { count[$2]++; text[$2] = $0 }
    END { print head; for (i in count) if (count[i] == 1) print text[i] }' file
```

... which, for the given data, would output

```
a b c
value5 4 0
```

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) to read all records into memory, compute a new column, `count`, with the count of records having the same `b` value.  Then filter the records on that count, only keeping the ones with a count of one (the unique ones), and then output all fields but the `count` field:

```bash
$ mlr --p2t count-similar -g b then filter '$count == 1' then cut -x -f count file
a       b       c
value5  4       0
```

The `--p2t` option is a shorthand for `--ipprint` (input pretty-printed) followed by `--otsv` (output tab-delimited).  If your data is tab-delimited, use `--tsv` instead of `--p2t`.

Comment: That `for (i in count)` would shuffle the order of the lines for output which may or may not matter.

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses `datamash` and `awk`.

```
datamash -H -sW count 1 -f -g 2 <input |
awk '$NF == 1 || NR == 1 {$NF = ""; print}'
```

Using `gawk`:

```
awk 'NR==1; 
NR>1 { if (ar[$2]) ar[$2] = "repeated";
else ar[$2] = $0 }
END { for (i=1; i<=length (ar); i++) if (ar[i] != "repeated") print ar[i] }'
```